# Etherpad service under debian not starting at boot

Tags: service, debian, init.d, etherpad

I am setting up a Debian 7.6 server. I have installed an etherpad (etherpad-lite) and put it behind an nginx web server. The etherpad uses mySQL. This is all working as expected.

Now I want the etherpad to be running as a service. So I've done what this tutorial sais:

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-etherpad-lite-on-debian-wheezy/

I've put the code in a script called:

```
/etc/init.d/etherpad
```

and changed the paths accordingly. This works! I can start and stop the etherpad using

```
service etherpad start
service etherpad stop
```

Now I want this to start at boot. I've put symlinks into the rcx.d folders:

```
/etc/rc1.d/K01etherpad -> ../init.d/etherpad
/etc/rc2.d/S19etherpad -> ../init.d/etherpad
/etc/rc3.d/S19etherpad -> ../init.d/etherpad
/etc/rc4.d/S19etherpad -> ../init.d/etherpad
/etc/rc6.d/K01etherpad -> ../init.d/etherpad
```

MySQL which is needed by etherpad is started the same with S19mysql. In the etherpad init script I've added dependencies:

`# Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs $network $mysql $nginx`

But the service is not started after a reboot. I still have to start it manually (which works!). I can't find any output in the logfiles dmesg or the etherpad log.

Any suggestions how to find the problem here? What log files would I have to look into? What might go wrong that the service is not started although the script does work?

I've tried to use higher numbers for the start order like S24etherpad as well.

Thank you!